# How can I restart the adventure level from level 1?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I want to ask how can I restart the adventure level from level 1? Do I have to complete the adventure level before I can start it again? I want to leave the game in between and start it afresh. Is there a way?

Answer (score 11):

One way would be to create a new user(just select "if this is not you,click here' button(check screenie) and remove the old one .

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unless you want to erase your save file, the only way to restart from level 1-1 is to complete the adventure you're currently on.

Pay attention, anyway, that by completing the game you'll start an "improved" version of the Adventure. You'll keep all the plants you've previously found, and Crazy Dave will choose 3 seed packet that you can't remove and you have to play the current level with.

Comment: Note: this "improved" version only occurs once.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you finish adventure mode, you can do it again. On the sunflower trophy, it tells you how many times you finish adventure. The other option is to make a new account, or delete your account and make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to start from the first level.

1. Go to the "if this is not you, click here" tab and select the "new user" area. For an example, if your new account was Hailey1438, you would start from the beginning there and still have your original file to play!
2. Repeat step one except delete your original instead.
3. Complete the first adventure, because after you do you will restart the game at level 1-1 again, but with all seeds unlocked.

Those are the three ways. Although you can always accept the fact that you are more advanced than a beginner. You even get an award if you did way #3!

**Remember: When you restart the game after beating it, Crazy Dave picks out three random seed slots that you're forced to use for that level.**

Answer (score 0):

Xbox 360

You must create new local profile. 
1) new local profile
2) sign in with profile that purchased game
3) launch game as profile in #2
4) in game menu switch signed in profile to local profile created in step 1
5) enjoy from beginning

Obviously not of use for achievement gathering but for those that just want to play the game through from beginning works perfectly

Answer (score -2):

1. Delete your old save game
2. Create a new one
3. Repeat 1 and 2